# How do I properly call a C# variable in Jquery. The 'variable name' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, webforms

I am storing a couple of values in my codebehind as a via `Request.QueryString` like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lblRow.Text = Request.QueryString["num"];
        string Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];
        string Image2 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt2"];
        string Image3 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt3"];
    }

}
```

Then I try to call those values in my jquery and I get a `does not exist in current context` error here is my jquery

```
$("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function () {
            $.fancybox.open([
    {
        href: "<%= Image1 %>",
        title: 'My title'
        }, {
        href: '<%= Image2 %>',
        title: '2nd title'
        }, {
        href: '<%= Image3 %>'
    }
            ], {
                helpers: {
                    thumbs: {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong. My only guess is that the jquery is getting called before the variable is being picked up, because it should be set.

Here is my formview where I am calling the rest of my items:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
    DataKeyNames="num">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="ItemType_Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>' />
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="ItemDescription_Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemDescription") %>' />
         <br />
         <b>Asking Price:</b>
         <asp:Label ID="ItemPrice_Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemPrice") %>' />
         <br />
         <ul>
         <li><a id="fancybox-manual-c" href="javascript:;">Open gallery</a></li>
         </ul>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue earlier this year. Try this out Skullomana

```
public string Image1,Image2,Image3;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lblRow.Text = Request.QueryString["num"];
        Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];
        Image2 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt2"];
        Image3 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt3"];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all about scope. `Image1`, `Image2` and `Image3` are local variables within then `Page_Load` method. You should declare them directly in the class and not in any method.

```
public class MyApp
{
  public string Image1;
  public string Image2;
  public string Image3;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      lblRow.Text = Request.QueryString["num"];
      Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];
      Image2 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt2"];
      Image3 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt3"];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so for example `public string Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];` Like this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define those variables at the class level like this

```
protected string Image1,Image2,Image3;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        lblRow.Text = Request.QueryString["num"];
        Image1 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt1"];
        Image2 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt2"];
        Image3 = Request.QueryString["ImageAlt3"];
    }

}
```